# What is the sequential order of the Assassin's Creed series?

Tags: assassins-creed-series

I'd like to start playing the Assassin's Creed series but with all the titles I am not sure where to begin. I'd like to start at the beginning of the story and play through the games sequentially - in what order do I play them?

Comment: If you want a complete timeline, check YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dC_vE4_a8mI

Answer (score 20):

The order for the main Assassin's Creed series is:

1. Assassin's Creed
2. Assassin's Creed II
3. Assassin's Creed Brotherhood
4. Assassin's Creed Revelations
5. Assassin's Creed III
6. Assassin's Creed Liberation
7. Assassin's Creed IV Black Flag
8. Assassin's Creed Freedom Cry
9. Assassin's Creed Rogue
10. Assassin's Creed Unity
11. Assassin's Creed Syndicate
12. Assassin's Creed Origins
13. Assassin's Creed Odyssey
14. Assassin's Creed Valhalla
15. Assassin's Creed Mirage (Expected on 12 Oct 2023)

Comment: For future reference, you can edit your posts, you don't need to delete them and post again.

Comment: @luka ash
Where does Freedom Cry fit?

Comment: Worth noting this is release order, and the only ones which have an actual story arc are AC2, Brotherhood and Revelations.

Comment: @AronBoyette Freedom Cry was a sub-story in the AC4 Black Flag game world

Comment: There are also the platforming entries in the series, AC Chronicles, including China, Russia and India

Comment: I added Freedom Cry as it is no longer available as DLC for AC IV but it is as a stand alone game.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the animus story, Assassin's Creed Odyssey chronologically is the first game, and as such it should be played first if you are going by the animus timeline order so it could be played:

1. Assassin's Creed Odyssey
2. Assassin's Creed Origins
3. Assassin's Creed
4. Assassin's Creed II
5. Assassin's Creed Brotherhood
6. Assassin's Creed Revelations
7. Assassin's Creed liberation
8. Assassin's Creed black flag
9. Assassin's Creed Rogue
10. Assassin's Creed 3
11. Assassin's Creed Unity
12. Assassin's Creed Syndicate

Comment: Actually in that order Rogue is before 3, got young Achilles in it and everything.

Comment: Assassin's Creed Odyssey is actually set quite a bit before Origins, chronologically

Comment: Black Flag follows Connor's grandfather, so it's before 3.